# Using ajax to load results from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to use JQuery to load results from a mysql database by generating json-p output.

This is the example output generated by the php script:

`([{"portfolio":"Foreign Affairs and Trade Portfolio","agency":"Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade ","program":"Programme 1.10: Official Development Assistance - Emergency, Humanitarian and Refugee Programme","funding":{"last":"182606","current":"338636","plus1":"349680","plus2":"361875","plus3":"373843"}},{"portfolio":"Immigration and Border Protection Portfolio","agency":"Migration Review Tribunal and Refugee Review Tribunal ","program":"Programme 1.1: Final independent merits review of decisions concerning refugee status and the refusal or cancellation of migration and refugee visas.","funding":{"last":"82985","current":"60667","plus1":"60656","plus2":"61237","plus3":"60897"}},{"portfolio":"Immigration and Border Protection Portfolio","agency":"Department of Immigration and Border Protection","program":"Programme 2.1: Refugee and Humanitarian Assistance","funding":{"last":"61086","current":"69320","plus1":"42720","plus2":"30774","plus3":"30158"}},{"portfolio":"Immigration and Border Protection Portfolio","agency":"Department of Immigration and Border Protection","program":"Programme 2.2: Refugee and Humanitarian Assistance ","funding":{"last":"66243","current":"66563","plus1":"73841","plus2":"91595","plus3":"92895"}}]);`

I'm not getting any results in the console or page and I am wondering if this looks right? I've never worked with Ajax before.

Does the output look correct? It has this tag 
   `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Any help appreciated,

thanks
Rosie
Here is the code (adapted from an example provided by Joe Chellman

```
<form action="" id="rep-lookup">
        <div>
        <label for="txt-program">search:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt-program" name="program" required />
        </div>

        <div>
        <input type="submit" id="btn-lookup" value="Look up my reps" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="rep-lookup-results">
        <em>When senators are found, they will be displayed here.</em>
    </div>




        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="_scripts/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script>
        'use strict';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#rep-lookup').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var 
                    program = $('#txt-program').val(),
                    $resultsArea = $('#rep-lookup-results');

                var requestURL = 'http://infoaus.net/budget/program_results_json.php?callback=?';

                $.getJSON(requestURL, {

                    'program' : program,
                }, function(data){
                    console.log(data);


                });
            });
        });


        </script>
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON, mostly out of respect for it being surrounded by (parenthesis) and ended with a semi-colon. However, outside of that it is valid JSON and then can be used within an ajax/javascript context to be used however is needed..

Comment: I did try removing those but it didn't change the result. I've removed them again. I still get nothing in the console or on the page. I'll add the code and see what that shows.

Comment: appears that this is a crossdomain `jsonp` request which is why the extra `()` are there but the callback function preceding it is missing. API may require a specific callback name rather than jQuery default of `?` If it isn't cross domain you just need to send `json_encoded` data

Comment: It's going to be an iphone app so I'm assuming I need to do a crossdomain request? You're saying I need to preceed the jsonp output with a function name- hence the ()? I'm new to js and ajax so I'm struggling to get a handle on the various bits and pieces.